# Google geocode and places apis both returning wrong results given a lat long

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-location, google-location-services

I'm currently building a location based app that relies on the lat and long of the devices being properly translated to a text location.

My current problem is as follows (using lat/long -37.8047079,144.9641467 as an example):

---

Both

**Places API**

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=-37.8047079,144.9641467&key

and

**Geocode API**

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=-37.8047079,144.96414677&key

return: **"8-14 Little Queensberry St, Carlton VIC 3053, Australia"**

---

However for some reason or another when the **same lat long** is typed into google maps itself it results in the location **135 Queensberry St, Carlton VIC 3053**

Which is a major problem for me due to the **routes API returning that same later address** Causing a mismatch between the two services

Am i doing something wrong and if i'm not, is there a way around it?

*Note that the second address is the one that i deem as "correct"*

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

When you execute a [reverse geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding) you should use `latlng` parameter instead of the `address` parameter. So the query

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=-37.8047079%2C144.96414677&key=MY_API_KEY`

returns several items. The first one is `Shop2/143 Queensberry St, Carlton VIC 3053` of type establishment, restaurant and the second one is `135 Queensberry St, Carlton VIC 3053, Australia` of type street_address.

You can see these results in Geocoder tool:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D-37.804708%252C144.964147

It looks like restaurant is closer to the coordinate that you provided. However if your intention is getting back a street address just filter the reverse geocoding results by street address type.

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=-37.8047079%2C144.96414677&result_type=street_address&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

This request will return expected result.

I hope this helps!